# Is it possible to filter real-time developer notifications (RTDN) from Play Store

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

Looking at the Google Cloud [RTDN documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference#encoding) it appears you can receive four different types of developer notifications for example, a `subscriptionNotification` or a `oneTimeProductNotification`.

If I have a webhook that is only interested in receiving a `subscriptionNotification` is it possible to setup a subscriber that will only push a specific notification to the endpoint and ignore the others for example, not push `voidedPurchaseNotification`.

Looking at the Google cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter#filtering_syntax) you can filter based on attributes however from what I can see you cannot filter based on the message body.

Does anyone know if this is possible to setup with the subscriber or does the filtering need to happen at the handler?